# How to make a quick css edit? and other high level questions from a new user

Tags: css

I am new to this cms platform. I have been asked to make a quick css edit to a website built on this platform.

#1 Do I make the css edit in the admin panel of the website , or is there another account that I need access to in order to make the changes?

#2 Can I simply go into the hosting account and update the css file?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to Craft CMS.

You cannot edit templates (or CSS files) via the Craft control panel, so #1 won't work.

Your #2 solution is the way to go, assuming the site isn't deployed from a Git repository, because your changes will be replaced the next time that code is deployed.

If you're new to the project, you might ask around or read any documentation about the project on its deployment setup, if any.